# Label display ignoring form boundaries

Tags: vb.net

Is the following possible and if so, what do I do.

I have multi-line text on a hidden label. When a user clicks a button, the label is displayed under a Textbox  (It is re-hidden by a second button click). This works fine.  However, if the label text is very long, the label is truncated by the form border(s). Is there a way to "ignore" the form borders as a context menu does?  I cannot seem to find a property, or method, to accomplish this. I tried BringToFront but that did not help at all.

I used a label as one project form has 3 labels of this type. Also, I am open to suggestions as to a better way of displaying help then a custom label.

Comment: Maybe you want to use ToolTip instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Sounds like you could use `tooltip` instead.

Comment: I was looking at the Help control but discarded that.  I am  working now on a custom tooltip as I want a different border and maybe size and other things.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Read the notes here: [How to increase ToolTip Rectangle size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/7444103). C# code, but it's almost identical in VB.Net.

Comment: You can set the Maximum Size -> Width of your label in design view Properties so that the width does not go off the edge of the form. Any text you add later will wrap and stretch the label vertically.

Comment: The Tooltip did not do what I wanted either.  So, I created a form with a label that was set to Auto-Size = True.  I then sent the multi-line text (with CrLf's) to the form and populated the label. I set the Form Backcolor to a "border color", the form to borderless and sized the form a little larger than the the label size to let the form Backcolor show as the label border.  Problem solved.  Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Mary:  No matter what I would do with the label it would be truncated vertically and/or horizontally by the form borders.  The label has multiple lines defined by CrLf.  Putting the label on a form and resizing the form one doesn't worry about form borders anymore.