# c# WinForm WebBrowser Control Displayed in Tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, webbrowser-control

I am creating an equipment tracker for a game that I play. Each equipment slot has a combobox that contains the different items that can be equipped in that slot.

What I would like to do is after selecting an item from the combobox, hover my mouse over the combobox and have it display a tooltip that displays a webpage. The reason for the webpage is that it's only a css styled "picture" of the item. It would be much more simple if it was a picture, but it's not.

Is there a way to display a webpage inside of a tooltip?

Comment: Well, you could [draw the rendered HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741246/7444103) to a Bitmap and [draw the Bitmap onto the ToolTip surface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/7444103). Or, don't use a ToolTip but instead a UserControl (or a simple Panel) and show your WebBrowser Control inside it (better always reuse the same WebBrowser Control so you initialize it just once).

Comment: Sounds simpler to me to take a screenshot of the picture and save it?