# Datatooltip Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, livecharts

Is there a way to display data in a tooltip with liveCharts which is unique per point?

I tried the tutorial from their website but I wasn't able to get it working.

E.g.:

```
Point   Name    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
1       Point1  1       2       3       4      
2       Point2  5       6       7       8         
3       Point3  9       10      11      12         
4       Point4  13      14      15      16
```

The Data is stored in a local sql-database.

The user can select which value he wants on the X-Axis and on the Y-Axis.

The tooltip should look like

```
Name: Point1
Value1: 1
Value2: 2
Value3: 3
Value4: 4
```

when the user hovers over the point.

Comment: You can *owner-draw* a ToolTip: [How to increase ToolTip Rectangle size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/7444103). It's not clear why you have both `WinForms` and `WPF` tags.

Comment: Because I want per datapoint in my bubblechart a custom Tooltip with data thats not in the chart and in the tutorial from livechart they used WPF and winforms

Comment: All right, that's your tutorial. But what platform are **you** using?

Comment: I think I am using WPF

Comment: [ToolTip Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/tooltip-overview) -- [Control ToolTips - Tutorial](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/control-concepts/tooltips/)