# C# datagridview Cell.ToolTipText increase Size of font

Tags: c#, datagridview, winforms

This is a code taken from Microsoft documentation, I would like to know how to increase the font size of the cell.ToolTipText
Thank you.

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ( (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Rating"].Index)
        && e.Value != null )
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell =
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (e.Value.Equals("*"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "very bad";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("**"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "bad";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("***"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "good";
        }
        else if (e.Value.Equals("****"))
        {
            cell.ToolTipText = "very good";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no Font property on that control (which I'm guessing you've figured out).  You probably will need to *Owner Draw* it.  There's a sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw?view=net-5.0.  I'd go back to whoever asked me to change the font and say "How badly do you really want an increased font size?".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/14171304