# How to change tooltip text font size?

Tags: c#, winforms

I changed in the properties OwnerDraw to true.
and added the Draw event.

```
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.HotkeyPrefix = System.Drawing.Text.HotkeyPrefix.None;
        sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
        using (Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 12))
        {
           e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f,
           SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
     }
}
```

First time i put the mouse over a control with a tooltip the text is bigger but then next on other controls the tooltip get black :

[image: first time working but on other controls showing black rectangles.]

before using the Draw event it was working fine but i want to resize the text font size.

Comment: Be sure to experiment with the [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.draw?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples), you missed e.DrawBackground().

Comment: Or [draw your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745899/7444103) -- You should use `TextRenderer.DrawText()` instead of `Graphics.DrawString()` and, as shown, also better measure the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need clear the graphics first.

```
e.Graphics.Clear(((Control)sender).BackColor);
```

Or just use the methods defined in `DrawToolTipEventArgs`

```
e.DrawBackground();
e.DrawBorder();
```